# Show TextView after clicking a button

Tags: java, android, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I want to show a `TextView` once I click the button.

My Android project runs, but when I click the button, it closes my app.

Obviously I'm doing something wrong.

This is my code:

```
public class AFragment extends Fragment {

Button button;
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
View mainView = (View) inflater.inflate(R.layout.afragment, container, false);
button = (Button) mainView.findViewById(R.id.button1);
addListenerOnButton();
return mainView;
}

public void addListenerOnButton() {
    button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View mainView) {

            TextView view = (TextView) mainView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
            view.setText("Do whatever");

        }


    });

}

}
```

**Logcat**

```
02-14 21:51:35.896: E/AndroidRuntime(1536): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-14 21:51:35.896: E/AndroidRuntime(1536): java.lang.NullPointerException
02-14 21:51:35.896: E/AndroidRuntime(1536):     at    com.test.capitalpostouch.AFragment$1.onClick(AFragment.java:35)
02-14 21:51:35.896: E/AndroidRuntime(1536):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4084)
02-14 21:51:35.896: E/AndroidRuntime(1536):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:16966)
02-14 21:51:35.896: E/AndroidRuntime(1536):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
02-14 21:51:35.896: E/AndroidRuntime(1536):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
02-14 21:51:35.896: E/AndroidRuntime(1536):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
02-14 21:51:35.896: E/AndroidRuntime(1536):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
02-14 21:51:35.896: E/AndroidRuntime(1536):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-14 21:51:35.896: E/AndroidRuntime(1536):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
02-14 21:51:35.896: E/AndroidRuntime(1536):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
02-14 21:51:35.896: E/AndroidRuntime(1536):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
02-14 21:51:35.896: E/AndroidRuntime(1536):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Does it force close your app? Can you print the log cat trace?

Comment: Yes it force closes my app

Comment: Please post the output of logcat.  You can do so by connecting your test device to your computer via USB and typing "adb logcat" in the command line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

onClick() does not give you the mainView as parameter, but the button that got clicked. either store your mainView on class level, or use getActivity().findViewById()

and yes, some log messages would have been nice!

Comment: Good solution, this would work. Though it'd be more efficient to use `getView()` instead of `getActivity()` because then `findViewById()` will only have to search through the fragment's layout and not the entire activity.

Answer (score 1):

In your onClick method the `View` passed in is not the "mainView" you are expecting. The View passed in is the view that was clicked on; so in this case you're getting the view for the button `R.id.button`.

Change the line from

`TextView view = (TextView) mainView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);`

to

`TextView view = (TextView) getView().findViewById(R.id.textView1);`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that, in `setOnClickListener(View mainView)`, the `View` being passed in as a parameter actually refers to the button to which the listener is attached rather than the view you were attempting to inflate with the `LayoutInflater`.  Remember that all widgets, including `Button`s, are also `View`s.  Try something like this.

```
public class AFragment extends Fragment {
     View mainView;
     Button button;
     public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
          mainView = (View) inflater.inflate(R.layout.afragment, container, false);
          button = (Button) mainView.findViewById(R.id.button1);
          button.setOnClickListener(buttonListener);
          return mainView;
     }

     private View.OnClickListener buttonListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
          @Override
          public void onClick(View button) {
               TextView textView = AFragment.this.mainView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
               textView.setText("Do whatever");
          }
     }
}
```